# Custom Validator not call in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have some problems with custom validator constraints. I want to validate a field code in my entity TicketCode.

But the validator is not called when I use if(form->isValid), I don't understand why.

My custom Validator needs the entity Manager to check with the DataBase if this code corresponds, else the validator sends message error.

**My Entity**

```
     <?php

namespace My\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use My\MyBundle\Validator as TicketAssert;


/**
 * My\MyBundle\Entity\TicketCode
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\MyBundle\Entity\TicketCodeRepository")
 */
class TicketCode
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $code
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255)
     * @TicketAssert:ValidCode(entity="TicketBundle:TicketCode", property="code")
     */
    protected $code;
 }
```

**My Class Constraint**

```
<?php

namespace My\MyBundle\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */

class ValidCode extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Code Invalide';
    public $entity;
    public $property;

    public function ValidatedBy()
    {
        return 'my_ticket_validator';
    }

    public function requiredOptions()
    {
        return array('entity', 'property');
    }

    public function targets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

**My Validator**

```
<?php

namespace My\MyBundle\Validator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;


class ValidCodeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $todayInObject = new \DateTime();  //Renvoit la date du jour
        var_dump($todayInObject);

        $ticketCode = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyMyBundle:TicketCode')->findOneBy(array('code' => $constraint->property));

        if ($ticketCode != null) {

            if ($ticketCode->nbMaxUse != 0 && ($todayInObject >= $ticketCode->getDateBegin && $todayInObject <= $ticketCode->getDateEnd())) {

                return true;
            }
            else {
                $this->setMessage($constraint->message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->setMessage($constraint->message);
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally my **service.yml** in my bundle.

```
parameters:

    my_ticket.validator.validcode.class:      My\MyBundle\Validator\ValideCodeValidator

services:

    my_ticket.validator.validcode:
       class:      %my_ticket.validator.validcode.class%
       arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
       tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: my_ticket_validator }
```

If you have any idea why my validator is never called, explain to me thanks.

Comment: Try putting the content of your service.yml file in the app/config/config.yml. If this work, that means you didn't load service.yml from your bundle's DI Extension file (See how to do it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)

Also, did you try to replace "@TicketAssert:ValidCode" by "@TicketAssert\ValidCode" in the Entity annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an upper V in your function name *ValidatedBy()*. It is supposed to be *validatedBy()*.

Comment: for me the same situation - not called, but the "v" is lower case - validatedBy()